# Hyper-V 2019 Core Server can't install windows defender update KB4052623?

Tags: windows-update, dism, hyper-v-server-2019

I am having a problem with installing the "Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2205.7)" Update on my Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2019 Core Server. Using sconfig it always says installation failed. I also tried to download the update file from update-katalog. You will find 3x .cab files and 3x .exe files on the microsoft update-katalog site for this update. I tried all of them. The cab files return an error, if i run them using dism:

> dism /online /add-package /packagepath:"C:\37049705_04c96011b32d783314a49ed52845bfe05357f68f.cab

If I run the .exe files nothing happens.

I also found on this site https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-for-microsoft-defender-antimalware-platform-kb4052623-92e21611-8cf1-8e0e-56d6-561a07d144cc
that Applocker could lead to this problem, if activated. But on my hyper-v server applocker isn't activated.

In the log file i found the following entries:

```
2022-07-01 09:53:57, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3808 TID=856 Failed to get the Update through CBS. - CDISMPackage::Internal_OpenFeature(hr:0x800f080c)
2022-07-01 09:53:57, Error                 DISM   DISM Package Manager: PID=3808 TID=856 Failed to get the underlying CBS Feature - CDISMPackage::OpenFeature(hr:0x800f080c)
2022-07-01 09:53:57, Error                 DISM   API: PID=2376 TID=1640 Failed to open feature Windows-Defender-Default-Definitions - CDisableFeatureCommandObject::InternalExecute(hr:0x800f080c)
2022-07-01 09:53:57, Error                 DISM   API: PID=2376 TID=1640 InternalExecute failed - CBaseCommandObject::Execute(hr:0x800f080c)
2022-07-01 09:53:57, Error                 DISM   API: PID=2376 TID=1584 CDisableFeatureCommandObject internal execution failed - DismDisableFeatureInternal(hr:0x800f080c)
```

I already tried the DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth scan and sfc /scannow. Still got the problem. Also tried to delete the distribution file as well.

Could you help me find out what the problem is and how to install this update ?

Comment: I suspect Microsoft will need to release another update to address this.

Comment: Hallo Greg thx for the answer. Did you hear about this problem before ? I will be relieved if there are some others, who also got this problem and there aren't anyways to solve it, other than it is really the update file which is corrupted and throwing those errors. Thx again for the reply.

Comment: Yes, the latest KB4052623 (4.18.2205.7) doesn't work on Hyper-V Server 2019. It gets an error "MpClient.dll version in package is 4.18.2205.7, but after update machine has older version 4.18.2001.10". They re-release KB4052623 about once a month, so it'll be interesting to see if Microsoft knows it's a problem and fixes it then or do an out-of-band update.

Comment: Just a note that KB4052623 has been updated to 4.18.2207.7, but still fails to install on Hyper-V Server 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed on 10/3/22 that KB4052623 install continues to fail:

- Did a clean install of  "Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2019 (updated Sept 2019)"
- Used sconfig to install all updates, all installed okay. Restarted as prompted.
- Used sconfig to install all updates, all installed okay except "Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2207.7)"

Note: If you then use WAC, Update, and attempt to install "KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2207.7)", it fails and goes into a loop of a failed attempts every ten minutes.  A server restart does not stop the issue and updates like  "Security Intelligence Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.375.1506.0)" are aborted unless you manually install then individually.  With sparce log information to examine, all I know for sure is that the server crashes every other day.

I have many servers running Hyper-V Server 2019 (Mainstream End Date is 1/9/2024). This unresolved problem is now in its third month.

Comment: Do you have a case opened with MS? Given the market share of the platform, it may not have been reported yet.

Comment: Update for Microsoft Defender Antivirus antimalware platform - KB4052623 (Version 4.18.2209.7)" succeeded where its previous versions 4.18.2207.7 and 4.18.2205.7 had failed (since 7/26/22).

Answer (score 1):

The latest KB4052623 (version 4.18.2209.7) successfully installs on Hyper-V Server 2019 now [2022-10-13].

The [patch notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/manage-updates-baselines-microsoft-defender-antivirus?view=o365-worldwide) for this version state `Fixed Defender Platform update failure on Server Core 2019 SKUs` although there was never acknowledgement that it has been an issue for the past few months.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same issue...reinstalled a server, etc. attempting to resolve this issue and never could get it to update. Hope they release a working update soon.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the updates in the screenshot from 19.10.2022, the KB4052623 update was installed too.
Or rather, as said above, Willie, his version is 4.18.2209.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtIvK.png)